# What does this command with two filenames in it mean?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

```
./getProductAccess.sh access-2014-09-04.log
```

Normally there is only 1 file behind `./`. Now there are two. It seems the second one is to provide input, but what should write in the first one to get the input? Because read doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

This really is beginners 101.

`./getProductAccess.sh` is the program to run (in the current directory) and `access-2014-09-04.log` is an argument supplied to that program.

If you're writing the program you could reference that first argument as `"$1"`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use read you can use `$1`.

So in your script if you will use `echo "$1"`, then it will give output as `access-2014-09-04.log`.

`$0` is the path(relative or absolute) of the file which you are executing. `$1` is the first argument passed to file, `$2` second and so on...